# I want to do a little calculation and pass the value to a TextView on another Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to multiply a value of one of the TextViews by 100, send it to the Model class and show it on a TextView on another activity.

I tried this but didn't work. I get this error

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

```
    private void getProductDetails(String productID)
{
    DatabaseReference productRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
    productRef.child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                Products products = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);

                productName.setText(products.getPname());
                productPrice.setText(Integer.valueOf(products.getPrice()) * 100);
                productDescription.setText(products.getDescription());
                Picasso.get().load(products.getImage()).into(productImage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: What doesnt work?

Comment: @JakeB android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException error appears when I run the app

Comment: myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(myvalue)) or myTextView.setText(myvalue+"") to convert the value to string always , otherwise it will think that you want to display a resource which is referenced using integer value..

Answer (score 1):

Try using Integer.parseInt() for the conversion you are trying, be sure to write it inside try catch (if the entered string isn't valid to parse to Integer)

```
try{
  cartMap.put("price",(Integer.parseInt(productPrice.getText().toString())*100))
}catch(Exception ee){
  ee.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to pass whole object to next activity use following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ProductDetails2Activity.this,CartActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourKey",cartMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in onCreate of next activity get your hashmap as:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = 
     (HashMap<String, Object>)intent.getSerializableExtra("yourKey");
priceTextView.setText(hashMap.get("price")+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem usually happen when you try to put a Interger into a textview text.

something like this:

```
final String valueStr = textview.getText().toString(); // valueStr = 1
int value = Interger.parseInt(valueStr)
textview.setText(value + 100)
```

instead of set text to 101 it will try to find a value of 101 in R table cuz you are passing a Int value to setText.
Just check yours setText and you will probably found one with a int value instead of string

Your problem is in this line:

```
productPrice.setText(Integer.valueOf(products.getPrice()) * 100);
```

try this:

```
productPrice.setText(Integer.valueOf(products.getPrice()) * 100 + "");
```